# MVVM pattern in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

When following MVVM, how does the ViewModel get reference to the View?

For example, a VM for a UITableViewController conforms to protocol `UITableViewDelegate`, and in the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, how does the VM calls method such as `navigationController.pushViewController`?

A naive solution would be to pass in the view controller when initializing the ViewModel. Is there any other better way to accomplish this?

e.g. In viewmodel.swift:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let vc = UIStoryboard.Main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "postDetailsVC") as! PQPostDetailsViewController
   let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PQProductCollectionViewCell
   vc.featureImage = cell.productImageView.image

   // Cannot call the following since ViewModel is not a UIViewController
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: i thought UITableViewController itself already conforms to UITableViewDelegate?

Comment: The code above should be part of the controller, not in view-model. A view model should be inert and is a part of a view subclass. It can convert any model object to the format the view can understand.

Comment: @ArunGJ If the code goes in controller, how does it customize the cell according to the data retrieved from network layer, which I assume is in ViewModel?

Comment: i believe view models should be only responsible for exposing data to your view controller. you should either have your view model in view controller / view, and not the other way around.

Comment: ViewModel and View are decoupling. It means ViewModel doesn't know what the View is. They are communicating through data binding. If you are trying to put view code inside your ViewModel, then you are doing it wrong and against to MVVM pattern. I would suggest to use this library: https://github.com/duyduong/DDMvvm which has a lot of base classes for you to start working with MVVM

Answer (score 2):

A general rule of thumb I follow is if I have to import UIKit into a view model, I'm doing something wrong. (I say general because there may be legitimate use cases for needing something from UIKit inside of a view model.)

As mentioned in a few comments, view models are meant to expose certain items to your view controller. You should refrain from doing UI related things directly in the view model. This can effect the reusability of a view model and doesn't allow the them to be tested independently of your UI code.

In your case, it seems you're using your view model as the table view delegate. It would probably be better from an mvvm standpoint if you created an extension of your view controller and implemented the delegate protocol there. You can do this below your view controller class declaration like so:

```
class ViewController {
...
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
...
}
```

If you need to do something to manipulate the view state from within the delegate functions, you can expose a variable or a function inside of your view model, and call it from within the delegate function.

Answer (score 1):

***ViewModel*** is pure *NSObject*. **View** is represented as *UIView* or *UIViewController* objects. Your **uicollectionView** should be in your UIViewController that ViewModel attached it. **ViewModel** hides all asynchronous networking code, model changes etc..

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    var viewModel: ViewModel!
 .......

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let vc = UIStoryboard.Main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "postDetailsVC") as! PQPostDetailsViewController

      vc.featureImage = viewModel.productImageView[indexPath.row]

      // Cannot call the following since ViewModel is not a UIViewController
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   }
}
```